# Multi language from external Class Libraries (dll)

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, multilingual

I'm looking for the best way to create a multi language application. I want to have the language files in a external `Class Library` so it's reusable for multiple applications so I only have to add  it to the `References` (and probably some code in the .xaml itself).

---

EDIT 1: With multi language I mean like Dutch, English, German, ...
The goal is to have the computer system to say, if it's in Dutch, the application has to be Dutch, but if it's in French, it takes English as default. This should be done in a dll, so it's not "hard coded" in each application I make.

---

EDIT 2:

I managed to solve this problem on my own. Thanx to the people who replied to my problem.

I solved it this way:

I made a `Class Library` and named it "Languages". I added 2 `Resources` named "Language.nl-BE.resx" and Language.en-US.resx" with both a `String` in the file named "exDefault". After that I compiled it and added the `dll` as a `Reference` to my application.

In the application I used the following code to get the `String` into my application:

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Languages.Language", System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("Languages.dll"));
MessageBox.Show(rm.GetString("exDefault", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")));
```

This will get the content of the "exDefault" `String` in the `en-US` source and show it in a `MessageBox`. To show the other language, just change `en-US` to `nl-BE`.

You will notice there is a dll named `Languages.dll` and 2 folders named `en-US` and `nl-BE` with each their own `Languages.resources.dll` file inside them.

---

**The only thing I'm wondering now is, is there a way to get rid of those 2 folders and embed them inside the `Languages.dll`?**

Comment: What do you mean by "multi language application"? Do you want to use different .NET languages in different places? Do you want to add some native components? Do you want to use dynamic scripting languages components?

Comment: With multi language I mean like Dutch, English, German, ... The goal is to have the computer system to say, if it's in Dutch, the application has to be Dutch, but if it's in French, it takes English as default. This should be done in a dll, so it's not "hard coded" in each application I make.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read the sections on *globalization / localization* in the WPF and .Net documentation. Also, you might want to check out this blog, where there are examples of how to use localized resource dlls in WPF:

http://wpfglue.wordpress.com/category/localization/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem on my own. Thanx to the people who replied to my problem.

I solved it this way:

I made a `Class Library` and named it "Languages". I added 2 `Resources` named "Language.nl-BE.resx" and Language.en-US.resx" with both a `String` in the file named "exDefault". After that I compiled it and added the `dll` as a `Reference` to my application.

In the application I used the following code to get the `String` into my application:

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Languages.Language", System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("Languages.dll"));
MessageBox.Show(rm.GetString("exDefault", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")));
```

This will get the content of the "exDefault" `String` in the `en-US` source and show it in a `MessageBox`. To show the other language, just change `en-US` to `nl-BE`.

You will notice there is a dll named `Languages.dll` and 2 folders named `en-US` and `nl-BE` with each their own `Languages.resources.dll` file inside them.

---

**The only thing I'm wondering now is, is there a way to get rid of those 2 folders and embed them inside the `Languages.dll`?**